# why large sqlite database can cause windows server tcp connection delay

Tags: sqlite, tcp, concurrency, lag, windows-server

I have a Windows Server 2016 machine that runs a server program, there're about **2.2k** concurrent requests per second. The server program only costs the server **25% cpu** and **25% memory** and **30% bandwidth**. It's written in c++, just like the [boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp). it just does some calculation and return the result to client in TCP, and it doesn't use the disk.

But it's very lag, I can see the lag not only from my clients, but also from the Remote Desktop Connection, it takes about 10 seconds to establish an RDP connection, and it's very quick(less than 2 seconds) if I close the server program.

<del>I guess some resources on my server is exhausted. But how can I find it, is there any tool can profile the system to find the bottleneck?</del>

**Update**

The server program uses all cores averagely by running 8 threads on 8 cores, I did take care about this, it's confirmed in Task Manager, all 8 cores used nearly the same.

I found the problem is: I'm using a sqlite3 database(**my.db**) to log all the client access, the server becomes more lag when the .db grows. Now it is **1.2Gb**, which causes the lag.

Then I tried:

1. Keep the 1.2Gb .db, just load it once at startup to read some configuration, stop recording new log, **no read/write access** while server is running, but it's **still lag**.
2. Execute `delete from log_table` and `vacuum` to delete the previous log and reduce the .db size to **16k**.  Then lag problem is gone, client request becomes **very quick**.

*Question*

Why the large database can cause the whole server lag? Not only for the server itself, but also affect other app like RDP connection, even the load is low?

**Server Environment**

- Windows Server 2016
- cpu: 8 cores (25% used)
- memory: 16Gb (25% used)
- disk: 40Gb (30% used)
- server program written in c++ with boost coroutine
- sqlite3 database with `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;` enabled.

Comment: If you are pretty much sitting at around 25% CPU usage, that would lead me to make 2 assumption that may not be correct, but could explain the performance issues; you are running a quad core processor, not itself an issue, but the application is only using a single thread, it is not balancing the load across multiple cores, and is restricted to only on core of the CPU, one request must finish before the next begins.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did take care about the multi-core problem, I've updated the post for this.

Comment: Show the DB schema and the actual SQL statements that are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) tools.

Launch procexp.exe [(Process Explorer )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) - use process explorer to find out memory and disk usage for your process, and other.

Use resmon ( Win+R then type "resmon" ) to monitor the network bandwidth when your program is running and when it's not.